# How to append new rows in CSV file python?

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I'm using python 2.7 and I have a program that when I take picture from the camera ,the data(phase,date,time,name of image) will be stored in CSV file each time when the image being capture. 
 This is the csv file looks like when the short code below executed.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzMTe.png

As you can see the "headers" which are 'Phase', 'Date', 'Time','Name' will be printed out again in the next line when the image being capture.

I want the headers just print one time on the top of csv file. As I strolling around some websites there is [newline=''] keyword that should work but as I'm using python 2.7 it's not possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```py
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'a') as f:

                fieldnames = ['Phase', 'Date', 'Time','Name']
                thewriter = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = fieldnames)
                thewriter.writeheader()

                thewriter.writerow({'Phase': _phase, 'Date' : 
                 _currentDT.date(), 'Time' : _currentDT.time(),
                                    'Name' : _nameImage })
```

Comment: You can maybe compare the first row and see if headers are added and not add it the second time

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312309/check-if-header-exists-with-python-pandas?lq=1

Comment: thanks, this seems abit hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple solution you can do something like this (not the most efficient solution)

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'r+') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    row1 = []

    try:
        row1 = next(reader)
    except StopIteration:
        print("No data is written to file yet")

    fieldnames = ['Phase', 'Date', 'Time', 'Name']
    thewriter = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    if row1 != fieldnames:
        thewriter.writeheader()

    thewriter.writerow({'Phase': _phase, 'Date' : 
     _currentDT.date(), 'Time' : _currentDT.time(),'Name' : _nameImage })
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, but your code doesn't work, it somehow isn't write anything, just an empty csv file.

Comment: the code runs without any error, but somehow the csv file was empty as this link. https://imgur.com/r8bnUWO

Comment: ```StopIteration``` exception was thrown which I was not handling previously.

Comment: I have updated your code but when I run it it's not even write the file which is data.csv

Comment: but I have tried to create a "data.csv" by hand before I execute the code , and the data is written lol , as this https://imgur.com/KLerJUP

Comment: This code above works fine for me. Does it give any error ? Can you check your logs ?

Comment: @huyhoangle is this not what you wanted ?

Comment: @huyhoangle the code works fine and gives a csv file which is comma separated. You can open this file in excel or any datasheet tool. You can read this file in python like csv

Comment: The problem is I will have to create the csv file prior otherwise your code is not going to write anything.

Comment: You can easily check if file exists and then create one if it doesn't. That wasn't the Acceptance Criteria for this question

Comment: ah got it. thank for the code, really appreciate it. :D